# How to "characterize" clusters (e.g K means)

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I ran the K-means clustering algorithm on the iris data using the R programming language:

```
iris_data = iris
#k means with 3 clusters
result<- kmeans(iris_data[,c(1,2,3,4)] ,3)
```

I then plotted pairs of variables

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
plot(iris_data[,c(1,2)], col=result$cluster)
plot(iris_data[,c(1,3)], col=result$cluster)
plot(iris_data[,c(1,4)], col=result$cluster)
plot(iris_data[,c(2,3)], col=result$cluster)
plot(iris_data[,c(2,4)], col=result$cluster)
plot(iris_data[,c(3,4)], col=result$cluster)
```

[image]

**Question:** How do you describe these clusters to a regular person? If you look at the iris data:

```
iris_data$cluster = result$cluster
    head(iris_data)

 
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species cluster
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa       1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa       1
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa       1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa       1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa       1
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa       1
```

With clustering algorithms, is it possible to make similar conclusions such as:

- Cluster 1 : WHERE Sepal.Length <5.1 AND Sepal.Width > 3.1 AND  Petal.Length < 1.1
- Cluster 2 : WHERE Sepal.Length <3.1 AND Sepal.Width > 4.1 AND  Petal.Length < 2.2
- Cluster 3 : WHERE Sepal.Length <1.1 AND Sepal.Width > 2.1 AND  Petal.Width < 1.9

Is there any way to "summarize"/characterize these clusters? Or is this impossible?

Comment: You often use the centroid of each cluster to characterize them, sometimes with a characteristic spread distance also.

Comment: Plus to this, you characterize a cluster by comparing it with the other clusters. "This cluster A is top on feature X and is distinguished, but it is moderate on feature Y, like cluster B is". So to say, comparative anatomy, as in biology.